# Error while referencing both AngularUi and AngularStrap

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-strap

In one of my angularjs projects, I am using both AngularUi and AngularStrap. When I click a button it should show a popup but it says "$modal.open is not a function". Upon searching , I found that this is due to referencing both angular libraries.

```
$modal.open({ template: '<h1>Hello</h1>' });
```

Is there a way to overcome this??

Something like Angular.UI.$modal or something like that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current versions of Angular do not have a way to resolve conflicts or fully-qualify the dependency you want.

So with that in mind, the first place to look would be whether or not you can eliminate the conflict (either get rid of one of those bootstrap modules, edit one to remove or rename the services and directives you don't need, or better yet, edit one to remove all the things you *don't* need).

On the other hand, you *might* be able to game the way they are loaded to get it to use the one you want. If you consider two modules, A and B, each defining `$modal`, Angular will use the dependency from the last module to be loaded.

```
var A = angular.module('A', []);

A.factory('serviceA', function(){
    return function(){
        console.log('using serviceA defined in module A');
    };
});

var C = angular.module('C', []);

C.factory('serviceA', function(){
    return function(){
        console.log('using serviceA defined in module C');
    };
});

// to demo the concept, i'm just injector straight. in your code, you'd just change the order they're specified in your angular.module call.
// notice here we load C before A
var $injector = angular.injector(['C', 'A']);
$injector.invoke(function(serviceA){
    serviceA(); // serviceA will be from module A
});
```

Above I want to use `serviceA` from module `A`, so I define it after `C`. If you want `C`'s `serviceA`, swap it.

```
 angular.module('myapp', ['C', 'A']);
```

However, if your application's module is comprised of several sub-modules that each may rely on one of those bootstrap modules or the other, you may have a difficult time getting it to load in the desired order. It could also change on you in the future if some Angular internal changes, or your dependencies change.

I would recommend the first option: eliminating the conflict.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Let me try this out and will get back to you.

Comment: I have replaced $modal to $bsmodal in angularstrap.min.cs. Now all works fine .. 
Thanks a lot for your help